# How to refactor array to multi-array convert function?

Tags: php, arrays, refactoring

I have an array with 'levels' which looks like this:

```
Array
[0] => Array
    (
        [level] => 0
        [header] => First h2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [level] => 1
        [header] => First h3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [level] => 1
        [header] => Second h3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [header] => First h4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [header] => Second h4
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [header] => Again h4
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [level] => 1
        [header] => Once again h3
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [level] => 2
        [header] => New h4
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [level] => 0
        [header] => End
    )
```

I am trying to get multidimensional array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [level] => 0
        [header] => First h2
        [childs] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [level] => 1
                        [header] => First h3
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [level] => 1
                        [header] => Second h3
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [level] => 2
                                        [header] => First h4
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [level] => 2
                                        [header] => Second h4
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [level] => 2
                                        [header] => Again h4
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [level] => 1
                        [header] => Once again h3
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [level] => 2
                                        [header] => New h4
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [level] => 0
        [header] => End
    )
```

And my function is:

```
function generateFromHeaders(array $headers)
{
    $newArr = [];
    $level1 = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($headers); $i++) {
        $currentLevel = $headers[$i]['level'];
        if ($currentLevel === 0) {
            $newArr[] = $headers[$i];
        } elseif ($currentLevel === 1) {
            $newArr[$i-$level1]['childs'][] = $headers[$i];
        } elseif ($currentLevel === 2) {
            $childs =& $newArr[$i-$level1]['childs'];
            $childs[count($childs)-1]['childs'][] = $headers[$i];
        } elseif ($currentLevel === 3) {
            $childs =& $newArr[$i-$level1]['childs'];
            $count = count($childs[count($childs)-1]['childs']);
            $childs[count($childs)-1]['childs'][$count-1]['childs'][] = $headers[$i];
        } elseif ($currentLevel === 4) {
            $childs =& $newArr[$i-$level1]['childs'];
            $subChilds =& $childs[count($childs)-1]['childs'];
            $subChilds1 =& $subChilds[count($subChilds)-1]['childs'];
            $subChilds1[count($subChilds1) - 1]['childs'][] = $headers[$i];
        }
        $level1 = $currentLevel > 0 ? $level1 + 1 : 1;
    }
    return $newArr;
}
```

Maximum level in passed array is 4 so recursion is not necessary, but i don't like this ugly code.
As you can see the deeper the level of the array element the more code it needs to find the latest subchild of subchild of subchild etc.

May be there are some better algorithms to convert simple array to multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Could you explain in short the rules nesting arrays in others?

Comment: Seems like a code review question